# Проблема в Django 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Когда пытаюсь перейти с главной страницы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
к страницы фильма появляется просто белый экран со странным url

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это происходит когда вместо id = pk в views.py я начинаю использовать url = slug и пытаюсь перейти по ссылке фильма

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import View

from .models import Movie


class MoviesView(View):
    """Список Фильмов"""
    def get(self, request):
        movies = Movie.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'movies/movies.html', {'movie_list': movies})


class MovieDetailView(View):
    """Полное описание фильмов"""
    def get(self, request, slug):
        movie = Movie.objects.get(url=slug)
        return render(request, 'movies/movie_detail.html', {'movie': movie})
```

при этом если ввести slug вручную все отображается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот как выглядит html ссылки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужен дополнительный код моделей или еще чего-то просто напишите об этом

Comment: Вы уверены, что проблема в Django, а не в каком-нибудь блокировщике рекламы в вашем браузере, например?

Comment: Да уверен, полностю отключал Adblock и блокировщик от Opera результат не поменялся

Answer (score -1, accepted):

я пофиксил баг просто копаясь в коде